# Probability of choosing cards from a standard deck of 52

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

> If I choose four cards from a standard $52$-card deck, with replacement, what is the probability that I will end up with one card from each suit?

Since there are $4$ suits, wouldn't the probability just be $\displaystyle\left({\frac{1}{4}}\right)^4?$ I feel like I'm missing something here, any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *With* replacement?  You put the card back in the deck before drawing again?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probability of four different suits is the probability that the second card is not the same suit as the first and the third card is a different suit than the first two and the fourth card is the last suit:
$$\frac{39}{52}\cdot\frac{26}{52}\cdot\frac{13}{52}=\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{32}$$